# Get json file for karma unit test

Tags: json, unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, systemjs

I want to get a JSON file in my unit test because I need to have it for my tests but I dont know how I can include the file

I run my test with karma and Jasmine. And my project is created with Angular 2.

The name of my JSON file is `'www/assets/mocks/emptyCalendarData.JSON'`.

Does someone know how I can include a JSON file into a spec file?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried to use HTTP get but then I got a system

```
let calendarData: Calendar;
http.get('www/assets/mocks/emptyCalendarData.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => calendarData = data,
        err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
    );
```

Then I get this error:

```
ERROR: Error{stack: null, originalErr: TypeError{stack: 'mergeOptions
get


eval code
eval@[native code]
__exec@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:1482:16
execute@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:3896:22
linkDynamicModule@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:3222:36
link@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:3065:28
execute@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:3402:17
doDynamicExecute@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:796:32
link@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:998:36
doLink@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:650:11
updateLinkSetOnLoad@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:698:24
http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624:510:30
invoke@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:364:34
run@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:257:50
http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:609:61
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:397:43
runTask@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:294:58
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:515:43
invoke@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:467:41
http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:92:33
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:397:43
runTask@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:294:58
invoke@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?b9a84410301a475a439d6b7b4e7eff0954f5b925:464:41', line: 38}, line: 821, sourceURL: 'http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?18a094f61af9f2ec0577ca3a337760d97719b624'}
```

Comment: How do you want to use this file? It's a way to configure the processing of your test?

Comment: I want something like `let data: Calendar = { JSON FILE }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that:

- import json if it is inside of your app: `import * as json from './test'; //will import test.json`
- download file using `Http` and do `map(res=>res.json())`
- for webpack use json-loader plugin: `var json = require('./my.json')`
- for gulp/grunt etc. you could write code generator

Comment: The first option is not good because I want it in a variable named `data` and the second option when I do that I get a zoneJS / systemJS error

Comment: why not just rename it then `import * as data from './test';`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run "npm start", the debugger complains that "*.component.ts(3,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './data1'." I have "import * as data from '.data1.json' " at the top of *.component.ts, and 'data1.json' has the same directory path as *.component.ts

Answer (score 3):

I stash my Mock JSON data into a ts file like a variable. i.e

```
export var getMockResponseJSON = { 'key': value };
```

Later when I want to reach this variable, I simply import it like:

```
import {getMockResponseJSON} from "../JSONs";
```

and use it in my class

```
expect(getMockResponseJSON.key).not.toEqual(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the `Http` class of Angular2 within your tests to do that.

Here is a sample within a `beforeAll` function:

```
beforeAll((done) => {
  let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
  let http = injector.get(Http);
  http.get('app/data.json').subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.data = data.json();
      done();
    }
  );
});
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/k6jxHf?p=preview.