# Angular 2: Import static json file?

Tags: angular

How do I import various json resource files into my `component` *.ts classes?
Do I need to expose my json files using "export"?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688887/get-json-file-for-karma-unit-test/36689175#36689175)

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run "npm start", the debugger complains that "*.component.ts(3,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './data1'." I have import * as data from '.data1.json" at the top of *.component.ts, and 'data1.json' has the same directory path as *.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

just do:

import * as data_json from "path to json file";

it works at least for Angular 5.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can't directly load the json file you need to eather load the file using http request or  place the json variables directly in your component