# Loading JSON Without an HTTP Request

Tags: json, angular, angular2-services

I am working on a project using Angular 4, NPM, Node.js, and the Angular CLI.

I have a rather unusual need to load JSON into an Angular service (using an `@Injectable`) without an HTTP request, i.e. it will always be loaded locally as part of the package, and not retrieved from a server.

Everything I've found so far indicates that you either have to modify the project's `typings.d.ts` file or use an HTTP request to retrieve it from the `/assets` folder or similar, neither of which is an option for me.

What I am trying to accomplish is this. Given the following directory structure:

```
/app
    /services
        /my-service
            /my.service.ts
            /myJson.json
```

I need the `my.service.ts` service, which is using `@Injectable`, to load the JSON file `myJson.json`.  For my particular case, there will be multiple JSON files sitting next to the `my.service.ts` file that will all need to be loaded.

To clarify, the following approaches will not work for me:

### Using an HTTP Service to Load JSON File From Assets

URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43759870/1096637

Excerpt:

```
// Get users from the API
return this.http.get('assets/ordersummary.json')//, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log("mock data" + response.json());
        return response.json();
    }
    )
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

### Modifying typings.d.ts To Allow Loading JSON Files

URL: https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Excerpt:

Solution: Using Wildcard Module Name
In TypeScript version 2 +, we can use wildcard character in module name. In your TS definition file, e.g. `typings.d.ts`, you can add this line:

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Then, your code will work like charm!

```
// TypeScript
// app.ts
import * as data from './example.json';
const word = (<any>data).name;
console.log(word); // output 'testing'
```

### The Question

Does anyone else have any ideas for getting these files loaded into my service without the need for either of these approaches?

Comment: When you speak of `service` are you referring to a web service or an angular service?

Comment: Angular service.

Comment: what do you mean by "in the same **directory** as the service"? Do you mean that there's a variable in the service that holds the JSON object?

Comment: Yes, I want the service to load the JSON and assign it to a variable in the service, and then return it as needed as other components call the service for the various JSON objects. They need to be loaded locally from the same directory as the `service.ts` file.

Comment: @StephenRios Just noticed you updated question with `service.ts`, is this Angular 2 you are working with? if so, please update your question to reflect that.

Comment: You could use something like gulp or grunt to concatenate the JSON into your service.js file during the transformation from TypeScript.

Comment: I was also confused and `service.ts` resolved the ambiguity. AngularJs is something, Angular2 something else

Comment: Question is tagged `angular` not `angularJS`.  The `angular` tag applies to Angular 2 +, not AngularJS.  Added the Angular2-services tag for further clarity.

Comment: @StephenRios But, your angular code is from version 2.x because you are using`typescript`. The tag description states "Use this tag for Angular questions which are not specific to an individual version".

Comment: "Questions about Angular, the web framework from Google (NOT for AngularJS). Use this tag for Angular questions which are not specific to an individual version. For the older AngularJS web framework, use the angularjs tag." - note the part that says `(NOT for AngularJS)`.  Anyways :)

Comment: It will become part of your build, but it looks like you just want `as var`  like  `import * as data from './your.json';`

Comment: You are correct, however this does not work in Angular/TypeScript

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688887/get-json-file-for-karma-unit-test/36689014#36689014 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found to this was using RequireJS, which was available to me via the Angular CLI framework.

I had to declare require as a variable globally:

```
declare var require: any;
```

And then I could use `require.context` to get all of the files in a folder I created to hold on the types at `../types`.

Please find below the entire completed service that loads all of the JSON files (each of which is a type) into the service variable `types`.

The result is an object of types, where the key for the type is the file name, and the related value is the JSON from the file.

### Example Result loading files `type1.json`, `type2.json`, and `type3.json` from the folder `../types`:

```
{
    type1: {
        class: "myClass1",
        property1: "myProperty1"
    },
    type2: {
        class: "myClass2",
        property1: "myProperty2"
    },
    type3: {
        class: "myClass3",
        property1: "myProperty3"
    }
}
```

### The Final Service File

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var require: any;

@Injectable()
export class TypeService {

    constructor(){
        this.init()
    };

    types: any;

    init: Function = () => {

        // Get all of the types of branding available in the types folder
        this.types = (context => {

            // Get the keys from the context returned by require
            let keys = context.keys();

            // Get the values from the context using the keys
            let values = keys.map(context);

            // Reduce the keys array to create the types object
            return keys.reduce(
                (types, key, i) => {

                    // Update the key name by removing "./" from the begining and ".json" from the end.
                    key = key.replace(/^\.\/([^\.]+)\.json/, (a, b)=> { return b; });

                    // Set the object to the types array using the new key and the value at the current index
                    types[key] = values[i].data; 

                    // Return the new types array
                    return types; 
                }, {}
            );
        })(require.context('../types', true, /.json/));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will get an error if you call json directly, but a simple workaround is to declare typings for all json files.

*typings.d.ts*

```
declare module "*.json" {
   const value: any;
   export default value;
}
```

*comp.ts*

```
import * as data from './data.json';
```

Comment: Man I really appreciate your help, but unfortunately modifying the typings.d.ts file is not an option for me either, as I explained in my original post.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly access variables in services from their object that is defined in the constructor.

...So say your constructor loads the service like this

```
constructor(private someService:SomeService){}
```

You can just do `someService.theJsonObject` to access it.

Just be careful not to do this before it gets loaded by the service function that loads it. You'd then get a null value.

---

You can assign variables to your service files the same way you do in component files.

Just declare them in the service

```
public JsonObject:any;
```

And (easiest way) is to let the function that called your service assign the JSON object for you.

So say you called the service like this

```
this.serviceObject.function().subscribe
(
  resp =>
  {
    this.serviceObject.JsonObject = resp;
  }
);
```

After this is done once, other components can access that JSON content using `someService.theJsonObject` as discussed earlier.

---

In your case I think all you need to do is embed your JSON object in your code. Maybe you can use `const`. That's not bad code or anything.

Comment: I believe the OP want's to access a local JSON file directly from within the Service, to then assign that data to a variable.

Comment: The question is around how to get the JSON assigned to the variables in the service, not how to access them once they are assigned in the service from another component.