# Angular 6 - The json file does not compile for to production enviroment

Tags: angular

I have a json file imported into my component (app.component.ts)

```
import data_json from '../assets/json/general.json';
```

But when I try to generate the production version using the following command I get an error:

```
ng build prod
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(12,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../assets/json/general.json'.
```

If I launch ng serve, it gives me a warning in the console, but it does not give me an error, I access the browser and I see the json loaded correctly

With HTTP, ng build --prod compile fine, but my browser console shows the next error:

```
core.js:1521 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.ngfactory.js:414)
    at Object.updateDirectives (core.js:10494)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10147)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10388)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10330)
    at Object.checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10153)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (core.js:8534)
    at core.js:4411
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ApplicationRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick (core.js:4411)
```

This is my json file (general.json)

```
{
  "imgsesion": "fa_closesesion.png",
  "texthome": "volver a la home",
  "logo": "fa_logo.png",
  "contact": "fainfo@gmail.com",
  "menu": {
    "background": "orange",
    "link1": "ESCRITOR",
    "link2": "MÚSICO",
    "link3": "AYUDA ADMIN",
    "submenu": {
      "link1": {
        "text1": "novelas",
        "text2": "obras de teatro"
      },
      "link2": {
        "text1": "compositor",
        "text2": "intérprete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: try this link : https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/493

Comment: I have tried this option, but the "typing" file in Angular 6 maybe does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the JSON file via HTTP if you don't want to parse the file until runtime. But I guess that doesn't make much sense.

See this for more information on how to load JSON:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39410788/4521733

Comment: Via HTTP compiles well, but I have detected a problem, I am loading the json correctly, but in the browser console, I get the error that I am going to add to my initial question, also I put the json.

Comment: @Eladerezador how does your loading function look like? My guess is you are trying to access "menu" before the JSON is even loaded. Please also note that an import is way better, performance wise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44313866/4521733
So if you don't have to edit this JSON _after_ build, use imports instead.